# Just before login-screen, a messages flashes by - how can I slow it down to read it?

Tags: boot, fsck

How? I'm talking about the screen that also informs me occasionally about drives being checked for errors... Are messages displayed there echoed to one of the logs? Which one?

Is there a way to "step through" the boot process?

Into which of the logs are messages at this stage normally written?

Answer (score 1):

You can always press the super key (Windows logo) and type "log", then click on "System Logs" and you should see a variety of logs you can browse through. They're all neatly organized so not difficult to understand them.

If you need more information, you can always manually check /var/log directory

Comment: +1 for pointing out that desktop app - I've always reached for the console to dig around in logs so far. BUT: the question is less "where do I find logs", it's more "in which log should I look for this specific flash message, into which log does this boot-stage write?" Thus the fsck tag...

Comment: not sure what messages you mean... you can probably check the output of the command `dmesg` or contents of /var/log/syslog

Comment: As this message flashes where usually the "Your drives are being checked for errors" comes up, after every 30 boots: where is the result/this well-known activity logged? (or is the result of on-boot fsck logged at all in case there is no error? Wondering...)